# How to restore a MySQL .dump file in remote host

Tags: database, mysql

i create backup from localhost MYSQL database(drupal) using PHPMyAdmin (file format *.sql). size of this backup = 20MG. i create new database in PHPMyAdmin my live(online) server. Now, when i import backup sql Files i see this error :

`#2006 - MySQL server has gone away`

i know this error **fix** with this:

```
edit ../sql/bin/my.ini
set max_allowed_packet to e.g. 16M
```

but my server support said: better way is restore mysql using:

```
mysql -u username -p dbname < file.sql
```

now, i don't know how to work with this command line for remote server?!

Answer (score 0):

You need SSH access to your server to execute that command using a terminal. If support told you you should use that command, I would think you have SSH access. The SQL file would have to be on your server, so you'd need to transfer it there first (using for example `scp`).

But if you're not used to the command line, I would recommend first spending some time learning the basics before jumping right into it ;)